# Auto slow scroll with HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I have HorizontalScrollView and 6 ImageViews in it. I'm getting images from Parse.com. I want the HorizontalScrollView to scroll slowly when the activity starts. I have gone through the references but couldn't resolve it. I tried this method :

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            horizontalScrollView1.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            //horizontalScrollView1.smoothScrollBy(500, 0);
        }
    }, 4000L);
```

But with this, it is scrolling too fast. Maybe I could process HorizontalScrollView in a loop, so that each ImageView goes on repeating itself infinitely. Is there any way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Wonder why you commented out         //horizontalScrollView1.smoothScrollBy(500, 0); as this should have worked.

Comment: @Hardik4560 its not making any difference .. Scrolling too fast to the right!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this one..

```
android.widget.HorizontalScrollView horScrlView;

Handler mHandler = new Handler(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        horScrlView.smoothScrollBy(5, 0);
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 1000);
        return false;
    }
});

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 * @author Hardik Shah
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.horizontal_scroll_view);
    horScrlView = (android.widget.HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView1);

    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 1000);
}
```

Comment: its not letting me to define Handler constructor outside onCreate()

Comment: How can we put this in loop so that when the last image come the scrolling gets start over again !!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45801/discussion-between-hardik4560-and-addy)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but should work:

```
horizontalScrollView1.animate().setDuration(2000).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    horizontalScrollView1.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
  }
});
```